# How to change the DatePicker - date format in sharepoint 2013 subsites

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I've updated the regional settings and locale accordingly but when I click on the date picker on the SharePoint 2013 subsite the date changes to US format.

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

While updating your regional settings, Select "All sub-sites inherit these Regional Settings" property to apply the regional settings to all sub-sites.

[image]t